# Running Flink's python examples

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I'm trying to run the python examples that come with Apache Flink 1.14.0 but keep getting errors. I installed per the instructions, and the `.jar` examples work fine, so I'm not sure what the issue is with the python.

For instance, the command `./bin/flink run --python /Users/[...]/flink-1.14.0/examples/python/datastream/word_count.py` generates the following exception:

2021-11-05 23:04:11
org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:138)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:82)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:228)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.maybeHandleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:218)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.updateTaskExecutionStateInternal(DefaultScheduler.java:209)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:679)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerNG.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerNG.java:79)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.updateTaskExecutionState(JobMaster.java:444)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$1(AkkaRpcActor.java:316)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:314)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:217)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:78)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:163)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:123)
at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:122)
at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:171)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:172)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:580)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:548)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1016)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1665)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1598)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.createPythonExecutionEnvironment(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:401)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.lambda$open$0(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:243)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.lambda$getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory$5(MemoryManager.java:539)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.createResource(SharedResources.java:126)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.SharedResources.getOrAllocateSharedResource(SharedResources.java:72)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.memory.MemoryManager.getSharedMemoryResourceForManagedMemory(MemoryManager.java:555)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.runners.python.beam.BeamPythonFunctionRunner.open(BeamPythonFunctionRunner.java:246)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractPythonFunctionOperator.java:131)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.AbstractOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.open(AbstractOneInputPythonFunctionOperator.java:116)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.python.PythonProcessOperator.open(PythonProcessOperator.java:59)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.RegularOperatorChain.initializeStateAndOpenOperators(RegularOperatorChain.java:110)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreGates(StreamTask.java:711)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTaskActionExecutor$SynchronizedStreamTaskActionExecutor.call(StreamTaskActionExecutor.java:100)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restoreInternal(StreamTask.java:687)
at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.restore(StreamTask.java:654)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.runWithSystemExitMonitoring(Task.java:958)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.restoreAndInvoke(Task.java:927)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.doRun(Task.java:766)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:575)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported Java version: 14
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.Environments$JavaVersion.forSpecification(Environments.java:106)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.Environments.getJavaVersion(Environments.java:355)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.Environments.getDefaultJavaSdkHarnessContainerUrl(Environments.java:402)
at org.apache.beam.runners.core.construction.Environments.(Environments.java:119)
... 20 more

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported Java version: 14
```

The Java version seems to be wrong. Try installing another version.

Comment: Good catch. Flink only supports Java 8 and Java 11.